# OpenLayers, adding all layers from a WMTS GetCapabilities response?

Tags: openlayers-2, wms, wmts

If I have a WMTS URL, is it possible to feed in the URL and have it automatically add *all* the layers onto my map instance?

Currently, I can replicate the demo, but only if I pass in options, etc. Unfortunately, these streams are going to be dynamic and I will only be given the URL.

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wmts-layer-from-capabilities.html

Answer (score 1):

In a WMS this can be done by requesting the root layer, not sure about WMTS, of course it's not actually that useful, because the maps all overlay each other, so you're likely to obscure some data

So if you look at this [service](http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/wms?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&) you can see it has six layers:

```
<Layer>
   <Name>BGS_EN_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology</Name>
   <Title>BGS bedrock and superficial geology</Title>
   <Abstract>
   ...
   <Layer queryable="1" opaque="0" cascaded="0">
     <Name>GBR_BGS_625k_BLT</Name>
     ...
   <Layer queryable="1" opaque="0" cascaded="0">
     <Name>GBR_BGS_625k_BLS</Name>
     ...
   <Layer queryable="1" opaque="0" cascaded="0">
     <Name>GBR_BGS_625k_BA</Name>
     ...
   <Layer queryable="1" opaque="0" cascaded="0">
     <Name>GBR_BGS_625k_SLT</Name>  
     ...
   <Layer queryable="1" opaque="0" cascaded="0">
     <Name>GBR_BGS_625k_SLS</Name>
     ...
   <Layer queryable="1" opaque="0" cascaded="0">
     <Name>UKCoShelf_BGS_1M_SBS</Name>
     ...
```

but if you want all of them in one call you can ask for the root layer [BGS_EN_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology](http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&LAYERS=BGS_EN_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology&STYLES=default&FORMAT=image/png&BGCOLOR=0xFFFFFF&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&CRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=49.8639,-9.80586479568672,60.8622,2.92769479568672&WIDTH=1020&HEIGHT=881) like:

```
http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&LAYERS=BGS_EN_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology&STYLES=default&FORMAT=image/png&BGCOLOR=0xFFFFFF&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&CRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=49.8639,-9.80586479568672,60.8622,2.92769479568672&WIDTH=1020&HEIGHT=881&
```

[image: WMS root layer]

But you can't see some of the data like the layer called BR_BGS_625k_BLT, because it is hidden beneath the others, and there's no way to discover it, because the map image is rendered on the server.  It's not a case of somehow dissolving the top layers.

[image: hidden layer]

Or you can ask for multiple layers, like:

```
http://ogc.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/BGS_Bedrock_and_Superficial_Geology/wms?REQUEST=GetMap&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&LAYERS=GBR_BGS_625k_SLT,GBR_BGS_625k_BA,GBR_BGS_625k_BLS,GBR_BGS_625k_BLT,GBR_BGS_625k_SLS,UKCoShelf_BGS_1M_SBS&STYLES=default&FORMAT=image/png&BGCOLOR=0xFFFFFF&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&CRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=49.8639,-9.80586479568672,60.8622,2.92769479568672&WIDTH=1020&HEIGHT=881&
```

[image: multiple layer request]

but the result is similar, you get one image, though you can determine which one comes out on top.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The images only overlay on top of one another only if the layers overlap, no? For example, I could have Canadian layers, USA layers, etc. All independent of each others geospatial region.

Comment: Sure, so in the last example the data from three layers is visible, though one layer partially obscures the other

Comment: So you're saying for (WMS, not WMTS) I can query for the root layer? How exactly does that look?

Comment: The request is the second link

Comment: I coded up a simple example for WMS and WMTS https://github.com/Schachte/WMTS-Layer-Parser. This allows me to loop through all settings for each type and dynamically add the layers. Since the layers are going to be toggle-able by the client, I feel adding all of them is fine.